# Children collider not getting called

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Context

I'm working in a pickup system in my game. I've a component called `AbstractSightCollider` that has a sphere collider and some `AbstractPickupableObject` that are the objects meant to be picked up.

`AbstractSightCollider` is attached to the main character, but could be attached to any alive entity or anything that is able to contain inventory objects.

[image]
The way i designed it, it's that when `AbstractSightCollider` detects an object, it fires an UnityEvent called `PickupDetected` and when the player leaves the range of pickup, it call an UnityEvent called `PickupLeave`

### The problem

I can't make `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` trigger.

### Some code

This is attached to `AbstractSightCollider`

```cs
public class AbstractObjectSight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public OnPickupableDetected pickupDetected;
    public OnPickupableLeave pickupLeave;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
        GameObject gameObject = col.gameObject;

        AbstractPickupableObject abstractPickupableObject =
            gameObject.transform.GetComponent<AbstractPickupableObject>();

        if (abstractPickupableObject != null) {
            pickupDetected.Invoke(abstractPickupableObject);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision col) {
        GameObject gameObject = col.gameObject;

        AbstractPickupableObject abstractInventoryObject =
            gameObject.transform.GetComponent<AbstractPickupableObject>();

        if (abstractInventoryObject != null) {
            pickupLeave.Invoke(abstractInventoryObject);
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class OnPickupableDetected : UnityEvent<AbstractPickupableObject> { }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class OnPickupableLeave : UnityEvent<AbstractPickupableObject> { }
}
```

And here are the properties:

[image]

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the problem.

`OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionExit` aren't the events that i needed to listen, because they work with rigidbody. My AbstractSight is that, a non body abstract sphere where the entities are allowed to grab items.

Instead, i used `OnTriggerEnter`, `OnTriggerExit` and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both objects (the one with the script and the one that will cause the trigger) have colliders and rigidbodys, I find if one doesn't have those the triggers and collisions will not work.

Comment: It can't have a rigidbody, because it's an "AbstractObject" (Sight field). Anyway you pointed me in a good track, i didn't need to use "Collision", but "Trigger". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rigid body on the parent object means the collider will work on ANY child component but the rigid body MUST be on the parent object.

Example:

MyProjectile has a rigid body and a collider - set isTrigger = true
MyEnemy parent object just holds scripts
MyEnemy childObject holds the enemy prefab including its collider,

Everything is set to isKinematic = true, with no gravity.

Everything works fine.